# Installtion Error with UCommerce and Umbraco7

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I am attempting to install Ucommerce into a clean installation of Umbraco 7.10. I have tried Nuget and the Umbraco Package Installer.  I am getting the following error after refreshing the Umbraco back office:

[image]

Ucommerce spport is not helpful - given that it is a brand new installation, it appears to be a bug in the software itself rather than anything  I have done.  Has anyone experienced this error and is there a fix?

Comment: According to the project compatibility on the our project https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce/ more people have problems running Ucommerce on Umbraco 7.5 and up. The latest version there supports 7.9 as the latest version. Have you tried downgrading Umbraco to this version?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently upgraded uccomerce from version 6 to 7 using the nuget package when i got the same error message above.

Somehow the database upgrade went wrong. The following solved my problem.

There should be additional column "AssemblyVersion" in the database table "uCommerce_SystemVersion" 
So added the column manually as following:

[Add new Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpFO7.png)

I updated the  AssemblyVersion column as following:

[Update the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8dKT.png)

Accessing the umbraco backoffice seems to re-trigger the upgrade process and the uCommerce_SystemVersion was updated with the correct installed AssemblyVersion.